# Disable explicit serialisers when serialising with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using the Jackson library to serialise/deserialise Java objects to JsonObjects.
My class has fields that look like this:

```
@JsonProperty("password")
@JsonSerialize(using = EncryptionUtils.Serializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = EncryptedStringUtils.Deserializer.class)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

And its being serialised using this code:

```
JsonProvider jsonProvider = new JsonProviderImpl();
JsonObject object = jsonProvider.createReader(new StringReader(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jacksonClass))).readObject();
```

Where the EncryptionUtils.Serializer/Deserializer uses an encryption key to encrypt the password.
I'd like to change the serialisation process such as the JsonObject received would be serialised ***without encrypting the password and without changing my class.***

Is there a way to make the ObjectMapper not use the EncryptedStringUtils.Serializer/Deserializer even though its defined in the class?

Is there a different approach to achieve this goal?

Comment: You could add a system property that is used in EncryptionUtils to not encrypt the password.

Comment: In general, I'd like all the fields to be encrypted except for a few instances that I'd like to export without decryption, so changing the EncryptionUtils to not encrypt would affect the general behaviour.

Comment: You could try creating a subclass and redefine the respective fields. Not sure if this will work though.